# Upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10: Black screen with Intel HD 4000

Tags: 12.10, boot, intel-graphics, nomodeset

Yesterday I updated Ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10. I also had to reinstall GRUB, but after rebooting my machine and selecting "Ubuntu" from the list, a black screen appeared.

Following [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it), I overwrote `quiet splash` with `nomodeset` in the edit options, as adviced. Now I can follow the boot procedure, and appearently something is wrong with my graphic device (There is a line saying `Load default graphic device [failed]`).

The login screen never shows up, the boot just seems to stop at some point. Is there any help? I own a Thinkpad X230, 8 GB, with Intel HD Graphics. The previous Ubuntu version worked just fine.